# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.(NEXT JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i am having this problem in my nextJS project and its frustrating me... when i try to render a component in my _app.js . this is the value of the (this.props ==> {"response":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySUQiOjEsImVtYWlsIjoiYWRtaW5AYWRtaW4uY29tIiwiaXNQcm9maWxlQ29tcGxldGUiOm51bGwsInJvbGUiOiJBZG1pbiIsImlhdCI6MTU5MTQ4MDMwNX0.uDuxahTU6fVAaHjy1uu8BDbAoi0u9QVq1vk4wCLNfAg"})

my _app.js code

```
class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Head> </Head>
        </div>

        <Component {...pageProps} />


      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default MyApp;
```

My home page code

```
import withSession from '../lib/session';

const HomePage = async (props) => {
  console.log(`i have entered here ${JSON.stringify(props.user)}`);
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="p-4 shadow rounded bg-white">
        <h1 className="text-purple-500 leading-normal">Next.js Finally</h1>
        <p className="text-gray-500">with Tailwind CSS</p>


        <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps = withSession(async ({ req, res }) => {
  const user = await req.session.get('user');


  if (user === undefined) {
    res.setHeader('location', '/login');
    res.statusCode = 302;
    res.end();
    return { props: {} };
  }

  return {
    props: { user },
  };
});

export default HomePage;
```

this is the error i get

Server Error
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in HomePage (at _app.js:32)
    in MyApp
    in Unknown
    in Context.Provider
    in Context.Provider
    in Context.Provider
    in AppContainer

Comment: maybe because your promise is not resolved yet, please add more detailed code.

Comment: Show the actual code that throws the error. The error message refers to a component called HomePage so you have to show the code to that component.

Comment: What are you getting in your destructed Component and pageProps? React will not understand the children if they're not ReactNodes. Probably place the debugger and see what's the output for those 2 guys. You might need some react hook to do the rendering.

Comment: i am using next iron session from this example https://github.com/vvo/next-iron-session/tree/2855c64e6b729f34fa304700b0912afce49062be  and https://dev.to/chrsgrrtt/easy-user-authentication-with-next-js-18oe  here is my code that checks if the user is logged in  export const getServerSideProps = withSession(async ({ req, res }) => {
  const user = await req.session.get('user');
  if (user === undefined) {
    res.setHeader('location', '/login');
    res.statusCode = 302;
    res.end();
    return { props: {} };
  }
  return {
    props: { user },
  };
});
export default HomePage;

Comment: i am using next iron session from this example https://github.com/vvo/next-iron-session/tree/2855c64e6b729f34fa304700b0912afce49062be  and https://dev.to/chrsgrrtt/easy-user-authentication-with-next-js-18oe  here is my code that checks if the user is logged in  export const getServerSideProps = withSession(async ({ req, res }) => {
  const user = await req.session.get('user');
  if (user === undefined) {
    res.setHeader('location', '/login');
    res.statusCode = 302;
    res.end();
    return { props: {} };
  }
  return {
    props: { user },
  };
});
export default HomePage;

Comment: Edit the question and put the code there. It's unreadable in a comment.

Comment: @GuyIncognito the code in my question is the what throws the error, thats the code in my _app.js file

Comment: Yes, it throws the error, but it's not the cause of the problem. The error is in `Component` which apparently is called HomePage.

Comment: @Mohit the output of JSON.stringify(pageProps) is {"user":{"response":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySUQiOjEsImVtYWlsIjoiYWRtaW5AYWRtaW4uY29tIiwiaXNQcm9maWxlQ29tcGxldGUiOm51bGwsInJvbGUiOiJBZG1pbiIsImlhdCI6MTU5MTQ4MDMwNX0.uDuxahTU6fVAaHjy1uu8BDbAoi0u9QVq1vk4wCLNfAg"}}  which is the JWT gotten from the server   but the JSON.stringify(Component) shows undefined

Comment: @GuyIncognito  this is the Homepage code                                                            import withSession from '../lib/session';

const HomePage = async (props) => {
  console.log(`i have entered here ${JSON.stringify(props.user)}`);
  return (
    <div className="p-4 shadow rounded bg-white">
      <h1 className="text-purple-500 leading-normal">Next.js Finally</h1>
      <p className="text-gray-500">with Tailwind CSS</p>


      <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

Comment: Edit the question and put the code there. It's unreadable in a comment.

Comment: @GuyIncognito i have done as you asked... please help

Comment: So you can see @Norbert that Component is undefined and that's why React is complaining. So either use React.useEffect and then do the rendering when you get proper data or you can play with some booleans to render once the data is resolved. Cheers!

Comment: @Mohit please can i see a sample code of what you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

As you've seen that your Component is undefined. So you can do something like this,

```
<>
{Component && pageProps && <Component {...pageProps}/>
</>
```

Now this will guard that your component will not render if these are undefined.

And I assume that once your props will be resolved by parent component i.e. your Homepage, it will automatically inform App component that it's props are changed and it needs to re-render it. Provided you take these as props in App component.

Comment: but why is the component undefined in the first place? i have data in my props and also i have rendered an actual component from my Homepage so what seems to be the problem with this?

Comment: Are you getting the component structure also  from server ?

Comment: i dont understand your question

Comment: I didn't get when you said you've rendered actual component from your Homepage. What exactly you're referring to?

Comment: if you look at my code in the question above you will see my homepage code.. that's what i meant. i exported default Homepage which is a functional component that returns html/jsx

Comment: Alright.. So your component doesn't belongs to your props. I guess all you need to do is import your homepage component and then render it. You only need to destructure the props and that will work.

Comment: but this is next js and i am exporting a component from a file  in pages folder, in next js you dont need to import it anywhere else after exporting it....

Comment: Sorry I am not familier with next js but what I knew why React is complaining and how you can resolve it I've already specified it in the sample code above.

Comment: i have finally solved the problem , apparently the issue was caused by me rendering an async function as a component, so all i had to do was take off the async key word from the Homepage function i was rendering.

Comment: That's great Nobert. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you're using "const user = await req.session.get('user');" while it should be "const user = req.session.get('user');", let me know if that helps (author of next-iron-session here).